# Ignored rest at the beginning of a section

Tags: notation, time-signatures, guitar-pro, anacrusis

I'm entering some fiddle music into Guitar Pro 7.5 and trying to handle a second section.

At the beginning of the second section, the bar is short (only two eighth notes) just like an anacrusis, but Guitar Pro flags it for having too few notes. I tried adding a dotted half rest before the two eighths and that fixes the problem of too few notes, but when the piece plays back, it has a long pause between the first and second sections.

Is there some music notation that I can use to say "it's ok that this bar is short a few notes"? Or instead, can I add some kind of rest that is ignored?

**UPDATE:** I found my answer in [this](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/44806/how-to-notate-pickup-measures-in-the-middle-of-peices) question.

Comment: Although some fiddle tunes certainly can have irregular (["crooked"](https://tunearch.org/wiki/Annotation:Old_Aunt_Jenny_with_Her_Night-Cap_On)) meters, I strongly suspect that what's really going on is that the division between the sections falls "in the middle of" a measure. If the second section starts with a 1-beat "pickup" or anacrusis, are you sure that there's a full four beats before that at the end of the first section (assuming a 4-beat meter)? If it turns out to be 3, you can look into splitting up a measure. Hey, can you say what tune it is?

Comment: It’s from Adam Granger’s fiddle tunes for guitar. Check out the first song, “Aces of Spades”. The first section is short by two eighths, but contains a repeat, so I’m not sure how to split it so that Guitar Pro does not complain, other than adding a rest to the first measure and then changing the time signature of the “pick up” measure. I’m transcribing for low G ukulele.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the time signature for that single bar. Something along these lines:

[image: 4/4 time, single bar of 1/4 time, then return to 4/4]

Comment: I just found that answer in another question. I updated my score and it worked like a champ. Thanks!

Comment: @Ralph Glad it worked. If you could, please post the link to the other question so this post and that one will be connected for future askers.

Comment: I’ll try to find that question.

Answer (score 2):

Since the clarifications in the comments, I should point out that as far as I can tell, the ideal solution isn't possible in Guitar Pro. If all that matters is the audio playback, then whatever gets the right result is fine. But ideally, you'd be able to insert a repeat "inside" a measure. You don't want to wind up with a measure of four beats plus one more 1-beat measure; for this tune at least you want to keep on adding up to 4. Consider [this excerpt](https://tunearch.org/wiki/Ace_of_Spades) of "Ace of Spades":

[image]

At the end of the first line, the first and second endings are mostly the same. The first ending, though, ends with a full quarter note E before repeating. The second ending, if you add up the rhythms, has only three beats before the double bar. The last beat of the measure is on the next line. So how do we manage to "insert" that double bar between beats three and four?

*As far as I can tell*, it can't be done in Guitar Pro. In other notation softwares, I'd often approach it by creating a bar of 3/4 and a bar of 1/4 and then "hiding" both time signatures. As a performer, if this isn't possible, I'd prefer to have the 3/4 and 1/4 time signatures visible, but not to have an "extra" beat in the song.